# PostgreSQL pg_dump syntax error in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

In ubuntu 16.04 when i want to run pg_dump it doesn't work i got this error syntax error. What is wrong ?

```
postgres=# pg_dump db_name > db_name1.sql
postgres-#
postgres-# ;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_dump"
LINE 1: pg_dump db_name > db_name1.sql
        ^
postgres=#
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) is not an SQL command.

It is a stand-alone utility, so you cannot run it from SQL query. 
Follow the link for more information.

For your case: type `\q<Enter>` to quit from SQL-client and repeat your command again using shell prompt.
Remember you should use your SQL-credentials.
I.e.:

```sh
$ pg_dump -U <postgres_user_name> db_name > db_name1.sql`
```